# Type 'example' has no member 'sharedInstance'

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I created class and I write singleton function called " example "

```
import UIKit

class example: NSObject {

class example {
    static let sharedInstance = example()
    var userInfo = (ID: "bobthedev", Password: 01036343984)
    // Networking: communicating server
    func network() {
        // get everything
    }
    private init() { }
}

}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    example.sharedInstance.userInfo
    // (ID "bobthedev", Password 01036343984)

    // ViewController One
    example.sharedInstance.userInfo.ID // "bobthedev"


}
```

But I'm getting error *** Type 'example' has no member 'sharedInstance' ***

https://learnswiftwithbob.com/course/object-oriented-swift/singleton-pattern.html

Comment: You dont need this line "class example: NSObject", remove it with { } it will work. why you declare example class inside example class. this it not needed. you just need one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a nested class.
Just skip the inner declaration:

```
import UIKit

class Example: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = Example()
    var userInfo = (ID: "bobthedev", Password: 01036343984)
    // Networking: communicating server
    func network() {
        // get everything
    }
    private override init() { }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Example.sharedInstance.userInfo
        // (ID "bobthedev", Password 01036343984)

        // ViewController One
        Example.sharedInstance.userInfo.ID // "bobthedev"

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned singleton about you, can you please tell me more features of singleton.

Comment: What do you mean by "more features of singeltons"? Also, as @PravinTate mentioned, types like classes should start with an upper case latter (I just modified my answer).

Comment: Can you please share some link about  singleton to learn more

Comment: Check this: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/avoiding-singletons-in-swift and https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/

Comment: both answers are correct, you can create singleton using any one of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have embedded example class inside example so when you are doing example.sharedInstance it is the outer one, so just delete the outer example class.

Answer (score 1):

Class name should start with capital letter.
No need to declare class inside class you need to declare variable for singleton, please check following code.

```
class Example {
    class var sharedInstance: Example {
            struct Singleton {
                static let instance = Example()
            }
            return Singleton.instance
        }
    var userInfo = (ID: "bobthedev", Password: 01036343984)
    // Networking: communicating server
    func network() {
        // get everything
    }
    private init() { }
}






class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Example.sharedInstance.userInfo
    // (ID "bobthedev", Password 01036343984)

    // ViewController One
    example.sharedInstance.userInfo.ID // "bobthedev"


}
```

Comment: class example: NSObject { } is my global glass I want to get properties from this class

Comment: I create class example with subclass of NSObject

Comment: Can I know the more features about Singleton...Please send some info about singleton.

Comment: @iOS If this is useful answer for you please accept it, so it will helpful for other people